# Establishing an inequality between the first term of an infinite geometric series and the infinte sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, geometric-series

An infinite geometric series has the first term *a* and sum to infinity *b*, where *b* $\neq 0$. Prove that *a* lies between 0 and 2b.

$ 
\rightarrow \text{Since the series converges, } r \text{ has to be between 0 and 1 }\\ \text{(}\text{using the geometric series formula, i.e } \frac{a(1 
 - r^n)}{1 - r}\text{):}\\
\text{The sum}=b=\frac{a}{1-r}\text{, where } r \text{ is the common ratio.}\\
\rightarrow b - br = a
$

Ok. Now what? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Note that $-1<r<1$. Therefore, $0<1-r<2$.

$a/b=1-r$